# Trim characters from string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to extract characters from a string.
I want `[a-z or A-Z or 0-9 or . or _]` all other characters should be trimmed from the string.

I have a regular expression that can replace characters but I want other way around, I want a regular expression or any other method that allows only `[a-z or A-Z or 0-9 or . or _]` and remove all other characters.

Comment: What was the problem with it then ? You can do it easily with regex ? what actually is the problem you faced ?

Comment: What is the difference in Replacing characters or matching when using RegEx?

Comment: Does `Regex.Replace(text, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]", "")` work for you?

Comment: Regex.Replace(text, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]", "") is replacing a-zA-Z0-9 _ with empty string and returning me characters which I don't want. I want other way around, I want only a-zA-Z0-9 _ and all other characters should be removed.

Comment: @Ali - You should try this code. Running `Regex.Replace("g%4 D-u!!u_e", "[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]", "")` returns `"g4 Duu_e"`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Ali - the `^` after the `[` says "not the following characters".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the RegEx pattern `[^\w.]` to extract only **a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ or .**

```
var cleanedString = Regex.Replace("yourstring", @"[^\w.]", string.Empty);
```

**Here is the explanation:**

- `\w` represents a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or _
- The `.` after \w would allow for literal '.'
- The `^` at start means everything except what follows
- `RegEx.Replace` would Replace any occurrence of **unwanted characters** (specified by pattern in **second parameter**) from **supplied input** (**first parameter**) with **empty string** (specified by the **last parameter**)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple function.
This will just keep the correct characters.

```
    private string ClearUp(string inData) {
        var reg = new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9._]");

        return reg.Replace(inData, string.Empty);
    }
```